Script to copy quotes from Zotero to Obsidian
I'm struggling to make this script run correctly more consistently.
I wrote this Bash script that copies a selected, highlighted quote in Zotero (a source manager), and copies that quote into Obsidian (a markdown editor), finds the note, titled $citekey.md and pastes the quote at the bottom at the note:
#!/bin/bash

echo -n | xclip -selection clipboard
sleep 0.4
xdotool key ctrl+shift+c
sleep 0.2

citekey=$(xclip -o -selection clipboard)

sleep 0.1

xdotool key ctrl+c

formatted_citation="$(xsel -o -b | sed 's/\\>/>/g' | sed -E '
    s/\([^)]* ([0-9a-z]+)\)[[:space:]]{2,}/\1/g;
    s/^> ?["“]([^"“”]+.*[^"“”]*)["”]$/\> \1/;
    s/^> ?[‘\047]([^’\047]+.*[^’\047]*)[’\047]$/\> \1/')"

sleep 0.1

# set your vault's directory in your system
directory="/home/Obsidian/

# set location for Zotero's BetterBibTeX .bib file
bibfile="/home/Documents/Library.bib"

# set vault
vault="?vault=vaultname&file"

# if the vault already contains a note called $citekey it switches to that file
if find "$directory" -type f  | grep "$citekey"; then
   
 #   new_file=$(find "$directory" -xdev -name "$citekey.md")    
    xdg-open "obsidian://open$vault=$citekey.md"
            sleep 0.2
                xdotool key ctrl+End

else
     # Extract details from the .bib file
    author=$(awk -v key="$citekey" '
        $0 ~ "@" && $0 ~ key {found=1} 
        found && $0 ~ /author[[:space:]]*=/ {sub(/.*author[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[{"]/, ""); sub(/[}"].*/, ""); print; found=0}
    ' "$bibfile")

# Extract title, handling nested braces
    title=$(grep -A1 "@.*{$citekey," "$bibfile" | grep 'title =' | sed -E 's/.*title = \{(.+)\},/\1/;s/[{}]+//g')

    year=$(awk -v key="$citekey" '
        $0 ~ "@" && $0 ~ key {found=1} 
        found && $0 ~ /year[[:space:]]*=/ {sub(/.*year[[:space:]]*=[[:space:]]*[{"]/, ""); sub(/[}"].*/, ""); print; found=0}
    ' "$bibfile")

    # Handle cases where the information is not found
    author=${author:-"Unknown"}
    title=${title:-"Untitled"}
    year=${year:-"Unknown"}
    
sleep 0.1

# If it does NOT find that note called citekey.md, it creates it
    touch "$directory/03 Sources/$citekey.md"
    sleep 0.1
 #   new_file=$(find "$directory" -xdev -name "$citekey.md")
    new_file="$directory/03 Sources/$citekey.md"
    sleep 0.1
# and then inputs a literature note template with authors, title, year, and MOC (for links)    
    echo -e "---\nAuthors: $author\nTitle: \"$title\"\nYear: $year\nMOC: \n---\n\n" > "$new_file"
    sleep 0.3   
    
           xdg-open "obsidian://open$vault=$citekey.md"
            sleep 0.2
                xdotool key ctrl+End
fi

sleep 0.2

echo -e "\n\n$formatted_citation" >> "$directory/03 Sources/$citekey.md"

# Delete duplicate newlines to maintain order
sed -i '/./,/^$/!d' "$directory/03 Sources/$citekey.md"


Sample Library.bib
@article{Chiang2005What,
  title = {What's Expected of Us},
  author = {Chiang, Ted},
  year = {2005},
  month = jul,
  journal = {Nature},
  volume = {436},
  number = {7047},
  pages = {150--150},
  issn = {0028-0836, 1476-4687},
  doi = {10.1038/436150a},
  urldate = {2024-02-10},
  langid = {english},
  file = {/home/Zotero/storage/AXWNRXAT/Chiang - 2005 - What's expected of us.pdf}
}

The intended use is that I trigger a hotkey for this script when I've selected a quote in Zotero, and it takes the citekey from the .bib file, looks for a markdown file with that name and pastes it there.
However, this is the problem I've been having. With longer quotes (I haven't determined if there's a maximum length) it doesn't always find the citekey and it then tries to find a file with the name of the entire quote instead of just the citekey, which of course doesn't exist, and I get the error in Obsidian ENAMETOOLONG followed by the quote.
I can't narrow down the problem because sometimes it works, even with long quotes. It's not consistent on when it finds the citekey and when it doesn't. I don't know if there's a problem with xclip or my use of it.
Example of what is supposed to happen, from Ted Chiang's 2005 What's expected of us:
This is what is copied from Zotero:
(Chiang, 2005, p. 150)  
\> “By now you’ve probably seen a Predictor; millions of them have been sold by the time you’re reading this.”

And this is what Obsidian gets:
150  
> “By now you’ve probably seen a Predictor; millions of them have been sold by the time you’re reading this.”

Any advice on how to improve this or make it more consistent is appreciated!!
Thanks

Can you provide an example input, at least? You are giving us more than 50 lines of code, which we cannot run. If you can't provide input, can you at least remove anything not directly relevant to the issue? Start removing functionality from your script, until you get to the simplest version of it that still reproduces the problem. This is also a great way for you to find what the issue is anyway.

What do you mean by example input? Thanks

Something we can use to run your script and reproduce the issue. How can we test your code? What can we run it on? Can you modify it to just print to terminal and use a simple input file? Can you describe a simple way for us to test it? We can't really help with code whose input we don't know and which we cannot execute locally. Simplify the script, focus in on the problematic part, and show us that.
